# Transparent iframe ontop of pdf in iframe

Tags: pdf, iframe, png, transparency, overlap

I have found the technique of putting iframes on top of an iframes to get round the z-index problem browsers have with iframes.

The problem I am facing now is I need the the iframe that overlaps a PDF (loaded into an iframe) to be transparent. Is this possible??

The reason I want to do this is so I can have a transparent png over the top of the PDF

Below is some code so that you can see my problem - you will see a white square in the top left hand corner of the PDF.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>

    <style type="text/css">
        #contentFrame
        {
            height:500px;
            width:990px;
        }       

        #overlapFrame
        {
            width:100px;
            height:100px;
            position:absolute;
            left:0;
            top:0; 
            background: transparent;           
        }

    </style>

</head>
<body>
    <iframe src="http://www.education.gov.yk.ca/pdf/pdf-test.pdf" id="contentFrame" frameborder="0"></iframe>
    <iframe id="overlapFrame" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't think it will take care of other issues in IE. If you have drop down menu going behind iframe which has pdf document, how will you manage to put that overlapframe right behind the menu. Since it is drop down menu.

Comment: did you find any solution for that problem?

Comment: Hi Chris, no solution at the time it seems that the way the browser renders things it was not possible. I just change the functionality so as the menu slid out I changed the size of the iFrame so it got smaller, as it slid back, the iFrame size increased.